# Getting a column in 'Access 2013 report' as semi-colon separated string value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a report - New customers, which shows a subset from 'Customers' table where the customer has added in the last one month. One of the fields in the report is 'Email address'. My requirement is that I want to add a button 'Send email to these customers' and this button should open a 'New email body'. I have figured out that.

Now the tricky part. How to get all the email addresses in 'New Customers report' as semi-colon separated list in 'To' field  of the email?

Can OpenRecordset be used with reports?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a string called `list` with all emails in a recordset, just adjust the `rs = db.OpenRecordset` to the [Record Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821454.aspx) of your report:

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WHERE [JoinDate] + 30 >= Date()")

Dim list As String

With rs
    .MoveFirst
    list = ![Email]
    .MoveNext

    While Not .EOF
        list = list & ";" & ![Email]
        .MoveNext
    Wend
End With
```